# Extra values in generating parentheses result

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```py
def generateParenthesis(n):
    stack = []
    def backtrack(openN, closeN, s):
        if closeN == 0:
            stack.append(s)
            return
        if openN > 0:
            s += '('
            openN -= 1
            backtrack(openN, closeN, s)
        if closeN > openN:
            s += ')'
            closeN -= 1
            backtrack(openN, closeN, s)   
    backtrack(n,n,'')
    return stack
print(generateParenthesis(3))
```

the output is

```
['((()))', '((()))', '(()())', '(()())', '()(())', '()(())', '()()()', '()()()']
```

but I expect is

```
['((()))', '(()())', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()']
```

Why there is a duplicated value?

```py
def generateParenthesis(n):
    stack = []

    def backtrack(openN, closeN, s):
        # If no more closing parentheses are needed, add the sequence to the stack
        if closeN == 0:
            stack.append(s)
            return
        # If there are open parentheses to add, add one and recurse
        if openN > 0:
            backtrack(openN - 1, closeN, s + '(')
        # If the number of closing parentheses needed is greater than the number of opening ones,
        # it's safe to add a closing parenthesis and recurse
        if closeN > openN:
            backtrack(openN, closeN - 1, s + ')')

    # Start the recursive process with the full count of opening and closing parentheses
    backtrack(n, n, "")
    return stack

# Example usage
print(generateParenthesis(3))
```

This is ChatGPT's result. I think the operation of the code is same as mine. But I don't know why the result is different.

Comment: Please clarify your expected output from *generateParenthesis(3)*

Comment: Just debug your code and you'll see. You're inadvertently decrementing `openN` before using it in a condition.

Comment: Soooo your working process is to ask chatgpt for code, and then ask stackoverflow to explain that code?

Comment: Beware of ChatGPT and any other AI platform. Treat what they tell you as a guide and not necessarily a definitive (or accurate) answer

Comment: `openN -= 1` will affect both recursive calls.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have debugged and think for hours but I can't still fix the problem with my code. I'm tired after work so I can't think clearly. With everyone's answer, I know how it works. Really appreciate your time and expertise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in your version, the local variable `openN` is mutated within the current call frame: `openN -= 1` while ChatGPT's version, it's only changed as a recursive call parameter:

```py
# ChatGPT -- correct

# ...
if openN > 0:
   backtrack(openN - 1, closeN, s + '(')
#            ^^^^^^^^^
# ...
```

In your version, the `if` structure is such that in a given frame, doing `openN -= 1` in the top `if` will affect the `openN` value used in the bottom `if`, making it one less than it should be:

```py
# Your version -- incorrect

# ...
if openN > 0:
    s += '('
    openN -= 1  # change openN
    backtrack(openN, closeN, s)
if closeN > openN:  # this condition is now less strict by 1
    s += ')'
    closeN -= 1
    backtrack(openN, closeN, s)  # call backtrack(openN - 1, closeN - 1, s)
# ...
```

On the bottom line, the call we want is `backtrack(openN, closeN - 1, s)` but yours is off by one if the top branch ran, decrementing `openN` by one and corrupting its value for the rest of the current frame.

Not only that, but the condition guarding the bottom recursive call that used to be `if closeN > openN:` in the correct version is now `if closeN > openN - 1:`. This condition is easier to fulfill, accounting for the extra results (more recursive calls == more results in the output).

The general rule of thumb at play here is: don't mutate values unless you have good reason to. Each recursive call frame needs to be computed based purely on its parameters. If those parameters are mutated locally, particularly in an `if`, the logic can easily change such that you're computing the result for a different call frame, or in this case, making a recursive call that doesn't make sense for the algorithm (the count of open/closed needs to stay in sync with `s`).

Many languages don't allow mutating values, and other languages make it easier to declare parameter values as constants. Writing this in C++ as `void backtrack(const int openN, const int closeN, const std::string &s)` would lead to safer logic, preventing the unnecessary `-=` at the compiler level.

Note that `closeN -= 1` isn't technically a bug since `closeN` is never used after the mutation. But it's still poor style since it could easily lead to a bug in the future if you decided to use it after a refactor or functionality change, so best practice would be not to mutate it.

If you don't like the "busy" recursive function calls with subtraction and addition inside the argument list, you can create new variables for the current values. Just be careful to copy correctly if these values are non-primitive (not the case here).

Another general tip: print values or use a debugger to see the differences between the two versions. Adding `print(closeN, openN)` above the `if closeN > openN:` condition makes one of the differences clear.

Answer (score 0):

When your backtrack function ends executing, then it continues executing the parent function.
For your code, when you do generateParanthesis(1), at the first execution you have:

stack = []

**Step 0 backtrack(1,1,'')**

```
openN = 1, closeN = 1
you enter in the if openN > 0
s becomes '('
openN = 0, closeN = 1
```

**Step 1 backtrack(0,1,'(')**

```
you enter in the if closeN > openN:
s becomes '()'
openN = 0, closeN = 0
```

**Step 2 backtrack(0,0,'()')**

```
You enter if closeN == 0
stack = ['()']
step2 ends
```

**back to Step 1**, the previous if was the last command, step 1 ends.

**back to Step 0:**

```
current state: 
s = '('
openN = 0, closeN = 1

we continue executing and we enter in closeN > openN:
openN = 0, closeN = 0
s = '()'
```

and then you do **one more backtracking step similar to Step 2**.

That's why you have 2 '()' in your list.

What ChatGPT does is not changing the values of the variables in the current step, but just send different values to the next step. This way, when you return to step 0, you still have openN = 1 and closeN = 1 and you don't enter in the last if

Answer (score -1):

Inside `backtrack` you are checking two conditions in sequence. So it is possible of both `if openN > 0:` and `if closeN > openN:` to be true in one run if you decrement `openN -= 1` outside of the recursive function call.

Note that the second condition has to be in sequence and just changing the second `if` to an `elif` will break the logic of the recursion.

So to avoid the issue, just decrement inside the function call and leave the value of the variable unchanged during one iteration!

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have two functions in one script and accidentally ran the wrong one for testing!

Comment: I acted rashly and actually thought before your comment that changing it to `elif` would be the solution. The Other function decrements the value within the function call, which is virtually identical to the solution in the second part of the question.

Comment: Thats some good advise. I edited my answer again to prevent others from jumping to the same wrong conclusions.